# How can I make euc-kr text file?

Tags: node.js, file-io, encoding

```
fs.writeFile("test.txt", content, function(err) {

if(err) {
    console.log(err);
} else {
    console.log("The file was saved!");
}
});
```

Content is euk-kr text.
How can I make euc-kr text file?